# Returning a value from try-catch

Tags: scala

Here is a method in Scala:

```
def method1(arg: String*): List[String] = {
        try {
          new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
            .map(x => x.getRawString.toString)
        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
        }
}
```

It complains on

```
found   : Unit
[error]  required: List[String]
```

If I added an additional value so that:

```
def method1(arg: String*): List[String] = {
        val result = try {
          new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
            .map(x => x.getRawString.toString)
        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
        }

       result
}
```

it would say

```
found   : Any
[error]  required: List[String]
```

which is odd -- isn't this the same as the first approach?

Anyway, what is the Scala's standard way of dealing with this kind of situations -- returning a value from `try { .. } catch { .. }` ?

Comment: You can get this to typecheck by rethrowing the exception, i.e. `e.printStackTrace(); throw e` or exiting, i.e. `e.printStackTrace(); sys.exit`, depending on what you want to happen - since thrown exceptions and sys.exit are of type `Nothing`, which subclasses everything

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that in the case of an exception, there is no value to return. So you have to decide what value to return in such a case. It can be an empty list (if you really don't care about handling the error - not recommended!):

```
def method1(arg: String*): List[String] =
  try {
    new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
        .map(x => x.getRawString.toString)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => { e.printStackTrace(); Nil; }
  }
```

A standard Scala way would be to return an `Option`, which makes it clear to the caller what happened:

```
def method1(arg: String*): Option[List[String]] =
  try {
    Some(new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
        .map(x => x.getRawString.toString))
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => { e.printStackTrace(); None; }
  }
```

or perhaps return the exception itself:

```
def method1(arg: String*): Either[Exception,List[String]] =
  try {
    Right(new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
        .map(x => x.getRawString.toString))
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => Left(e)
  }
```

Since this pattern is relativelly common, there is a special Scala class [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try) just for this purpose, that gives these concepts meaningful names and adds many helpful methods. `Try[A]` encapsulates the result of a computation that returns `A`, or an exception if the computation failed:

```
 sealed abstract class Try[+T]
 final case class Success[+T](value: T) extends Try[T]
 final case class Failure[+T](exception: Throwable) extends Try[T]
```

so a literal rewrite of your method would be

```
def method1(arg: String*): Try[List[String]] =
  try {
    Success(new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
        .map(x => x.getRawString.toString))
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => Failure(e)
  }
```

But of course Scala has methods for this pattern (after all that's what `Try` is for), so you can write just

```
def method1(arg: String*): Try[List[String]] =
  Try { new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
        .map(x => x.getRawString.toString)) }
```

(There is a slight difference, `Try { ... }` also [catches some `Error`s](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.control.NonFatal$)).

Comment: Shouldn't we use Try companion object to construct Success/Failure?

Answer (score 6):

It complains because not all branches return the result:

```
def method1(arg: String*): List[String] = {
        try {
          new MyClass(new URL(arg(0)))
            .map(x => x.getRawString.toString) // ok, here I know what to do
        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace() // ???? What to return here??? 
                                                   // ok, will return Unit
        }
}
```

The common type of Something and Unit is Any. So what you need to do in both cases (with, or without result variable) is to return value in both branches (possibly some dummy value, like empty List in catch case).

**EDIT**

The errors are different because without val compiler can track that flow down to the branch and notice that function return type and catch result are different. With val there was no type constraints on val so it can happily **infer** that `val result` has Any type and then, when you return result it confronts with function result type. If you specify result type explicitly as `val result: List[String] = ...` error message will be the same.

Comment: It makes sense. But what's the difference between 2 my approaches (with and without using val result)? They have to return the same type, but the errors are different for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala such things should be better done with monadic style:

```
def fun(arg: Strign*): Option[List[String]] = Try {
    new MyClass(new URL(arg(0))).map(_.getRawString.toString)
}.toOption
```

**Update**

If you look at the implementation of Try's apply you'll see and interesting code:

```
/** Constructs a `Try` using the by-name parameter.  This
 * method will ensure any non-fatal exception is caught and a
 * `Failure` object is returned.
 */
def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
  try Success(r) catch {
    case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
  }
```

so Try is just a wrapper for try/catch for monadic chaining

Comment: You could replace `toOption` with `.map{ Some (_)}.recover{ case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace(); None }.get` to get behavior like in question.

Comment: @senia toOption is shorter and i wouldn't do it in such a way beacuse of useless side effects

Comment: how do I do that with using operator "try", not a method "Try"?

Comment: I wouldn't say that logging is useless.

Comment: @senia completely agree with you, but logging can be done with [Writer](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Writer.html) monad

Comment: @MariusKavansky check a little update, trying to avoid method calls in case of performance won't give you much, cause, for example, loops are  just a syntactic sugar around monadic operations

Answer (score 1):

You could pass "null" as return type for most of the objects and String Types(which are subtypes of AnyRef). For example please see below

```
def execute_rs(sql:String): ResultSet = {



try {
  println("SQL IS " + sql)

  val con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
  // println("statemetn created1")
  val stmt = con.createStatement()
  //println("statemetn created")
  //str.foreach( i =>statement.addBatch(i))
  val rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)

  return rs
}
catch  {
  case e: SQLException=> {println("exception occured in oracle sql insertion"+e); null}

  case e: Exception=> {println("Common exception occured:"+e);null}
  case _:Throwable => {println("some other exception occured");null}

}
```